# How to retrieve custom error object from a failed httpClient call?

Tags: c#, .net-core, error-handling, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm quite new to .Net Core Web API and have spent a few days looking for an answer but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for. What I want to know is how to retrieve the custom object that is pass from an API action back to the client via an ActionResult (BadRequest(), NotFound()...etc.)

So I created a new Web API project in VS2019 and updated the default Get method of the WeatherForecastController like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
    {
        return NotFound(new { Message = "Could not find data", Suggestion = "Refine your search" });
    }
```

When testing in Postman, I can get the expected output of Status = 404 and body is

```
    {
        "message": "Could not find data",
        "suggestion": "Refine your search"
    }
```

But in the client project, I just don't know how I can retrieve that custom error object.

My client code is like this:

```
    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44377/");
            WeatherForcasts = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForcast[]>("weatherforecast");
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            hasError = true;
        }
    }
```

I understand that if the API action does not return a success status code (such as 200) then this will raise an HttpRequestException. But I can't find a away to get that custom error object out from the HttpRequestException.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
public async Task OnGet()
    {
    
    using var client = new HttpClient(); 
    var baseAddress ="https://localhost:44377");
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            
    var response= await client.GetAsync(baseAddress);
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString(); // shoud be "NotFound"
    var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);// should be 
// "{{"message":"Could not find data","suggestion": "Refine your search"}}"
           ....
        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey. I guess GetFromJsonAsync from System.Net.Http.Json that is supposed to make calling API easier, will not be able to achieve the flexibility that I need. I've gladly taken your approach as a base to build my solution. Thank you!.